# There is problem with checkbox. I want to delete the content with delete button when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, checkboxlist

I trying to make a web application but there is a small problem in checkbox. whenever I select the checkbox it gives me output saying undefined. I want to delete the content with delete button when checkbox is selected I am not able to catch the problem what exactly causing it can anyone explain me. need Help

```js
var btnAdd = document.getElementById("add");
var btnRem = document.getElementById("rem");
var container = document.getElementById("cont");
var frm = document.getElementById("frm");

btnAdd.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("country");
  var h = document.getElementById("country").value;

  var element4 = document.createElement("input");
  element4.type = "checkbox";
  element4.id = "check";

  if (!x || !h) {
  } else {
    if (y.selectedIndex == 0) {
    } else {
      var base = document.createElement("div");
      var b = container.appendChild(base);
      b.id = "base";

      var element = document.createElement("div");
      var d = b.appendChild(element);

      d.appendChild(element4);

      var element1 = document.createElement("input");
      d.appendChild(element1);
      element1.value = x;
      element1.id = "text2";
      element1.readOnly = true;

      var array = new Array();

      for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        array.push(y.options[i].text);
      }

      var element = document.createElement("div");
      var d1 = b.appendChild(element);

      var element2 = document.createElement("select");
      var O = d1.appendChild(element2);

      for (var j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        O.innerHTML +=
          "<option value=" + array[j] + ">" + array[j] + "</option>";
      }

      O.value = h;

      frm.reset();
      y.selectedIndex = 0;

    
    }
  }


btnRem.addEventListener("click",()=>{

    var g = document.getElementById("check").checked;
        
        if ( g == true ) {
            alert( this.value )
            this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
            ;


        } 
})


 



});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input,button{
    border-radius: none;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.select-country{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container{
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.container-1{
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
form{
    max-width: initial;
}
.container-1 :first-child{
    flex: 3;
}
.container-1 div{
    flex: 1;
}

.container-1 div input,.container-1 div select{
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

#add,#rem{
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.container-2{
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.container-2 #base{
display: flex;
padding: 10px 0;
}
.container-2 :first-child{
flex: 3;
display: flex;
}

.container-2 :first-child #check{
    flex: 0.1;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.container-2 :first-child #text2{
    flex: 3;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.container-2 div{
flex: 1;
}

.container-2 div select{
    padding: 5px 0;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="select-country">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="container-1">
          <div>
            <form action="" id="frm"><input type="text" id="txt" /></form>
          </div>
          <div>
            <form action="" id="frm" onsubmit="return false">
              <select id="country">
                <option value="select-country" selected disabled>
                  select country
                </option>
                <option value="India">India</option>
                <option value="S.Korea">S.Korea</option>
                <option value="China">China</option>
                <option value="UAE">UAE</option>
                <option value="finland">finland</option>
                <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                <option value="France">France</option>
                <option value="UK">UK</option>
                <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                <option value="USA">USA</option>
                <option value="Austrailia">Austrailia</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button id="add" type="submit">Add</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button id="rem" type="submit">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-2" id="cont"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give the exact error message? Does it specify which line it's erroring on?

Comment: Javascript file from line 62. there is delete issue. I want to delete random any row after click the check box and then pressing delete button. but It code not working.

Answer (score 0):

**this** in a context of an arrow function is the parent scope usually global or window, you can read about it [here](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc), if you replace `this.value` with `document.getElementById("check").value` it will return the checkbox value and when you click on yes it will delete the checked row.

Also if you'll want to delete multiple checked rows you'll need to use different selector eg. **getElementsByTagName**, or **querySelectorAll** to get a collection of elements instead of a single one by ID(ids should be unique so implement some sort of indexing also, since your website has multiple duplicates of IDs)

Also your JS is malformed, the addButton event wiring has no closing tags, copy and paste this code to your scripts:

```
        var btnAdd = document.getElementById("add");
        var btnRem = document.getElementById("rem");
        var container = document.getElementById("cont");
        var frm = document.getElementById("frm");

        btnAdd.addEventListener("click", () => {
            var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("country");
            var h = document.getElementById("country").value;

            var element4 = document.createElement("input");
            element4.type = "checkbox";
            element4.id = "check";

            if (!x || !h) {
            } else {
                if (y.selectedIndex == 0) {
                } else {
                    var base = document.createElement("div");
                    var b = container.appendChild(base);
                    b.id = "base";

                    var element = document.createElement("div");
                    var d = b.appendChild(element);

                    d.appendChild(element4);

                    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
                    d.appendChild(element1);
                    element1.value = x;
                    element1.id = "text2";
                    element1.readOnly = true;

                    var array = new Array();

                    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                        array.push(y.options[i].text);
                    }

                    var element = document.createElement("div");
                    var d1 = b.appendChild(element);

                    var element2 = document.createElement("select");
                    var O = d1.appendChild(element2);

                    for (var j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                        O.innerHTML +=
                            "<option value=" + array[j] + ">" + array[j] + "</option>";
                    }

                    O.value = h;

                    frm.reset();
                    y.selectedIndex = 0;


                }
            }
        });

        btnRem.addEventListener("click",()=> {
            var checkbox = document.getElementById("check");

            if (checkbox.checked) {
                alert(checkbox.value)
                checkbox.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your feedback that really make my day. The code works but It only delete the checked row from the first row only. Let if I delete any random row say row 4  code not working . What I do to delete randomly any row .

Comment: You need a collecton of elements, I mentioned it in the 2nd paragraph of my answer, you need a collection of all the checkboxes, then you iterate over all of those checkboxes and check if their checked property is set to true, if so you delete that row, remember to also update the collection, otherwise it will generate bugs.